# Debug a program that also takes arguments through stdin

Tags: bash

I have a program `mywc` that is erroneous when I send a 128 characters long string to it like this:

```
(head -c 128 /dev/zero | tr '\0' '*') | ./mywc
```

I also have a debugger `nemiver` that I usually use like this:

```
nemiver some_program
```

And this will open a debugger to start debugging. But when I try to open `mywc` like this:

```
nemiver (head -c 128 /dev/zero | tr '\0' '*') | ./mywc.orig
```

it does not work. I get an error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `head'
```

How can I debug my program and pass an argument to it at the same time?

Comment: not sure how `nemiver` works but it most probably is `nemiver "head -c 128 /dev/zero | tr '\0' '*' | ./mywc.orig"`

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: Oh, Nemiver is a C/C++ debugger; you may try `head -c 128 /dev/zero | tr '\0' '*' | nemiver mywc`

Comment: @Fravadona This runs the debugging session, but during the debugging session program hangs as if it is waiting for stdin. What can be done?

Comment: Nemiver doesn't seem to provide any way to redirect its stdin to the stdin of the debugged program; you'll have to change your code for making it accept a file argument